# Issues mounting Azure Files using VM Custom Extensions in Windows VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

I am trying to mount an Azure File share when I provision a VM using Powershell. The share does show up, but is "disconnected" because the username or password is incorrect.
If I RDP into the server and run the script myself, the file share mounts without a problem.
Below is what I am using in powershell script and  ARM TEMPLATE extension resource.

```
{
   "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
   "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
   "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachines_azvmtest_name'), '/newCustomScriptExtension')]",
   "location": "westus",
   "dependsOn": [
       "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',parameters('virtualMachines_azvmtest_name'))]"
   ],
   "properties": {
       "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
       "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
       "typeHandlerVersion": "1.9",
       "autoUpgradeMinorVersion":true,
       "settings": {

"fileUris": [
          "https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/fileshare/fileshare.ps1#key is masked"


       ],
       "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File fileshare.ps1"
                },
"protectedSettings": {}
   }
 }

Below is the power shell code:

Invoke-Expression -Command ("cmdkey /add:`"XYZ.file.core.windows.net`" /user:`"Azure\XYZ`" /pass:`"KEY MASKED`"")
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "KEY MASKED" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "AZURE\XYZ", $password
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\XYZ.file.core.windows.net\abc"  -Credential $credential -Persist
```

extension is provisioned successfully but I am not able to open the mounted fileshare it shows as disconnected .

Comment: Could you please check if your VM has the certificate of the share in Credential Manager?

Comment: I checked its not there though in VM extension it shows cmdkey /add command executed successfully.

Comment: I think it is the reason that we can not access the file share. The `cmdkey` does not add the certificate in your machine.

Comment: Yes that is the issue but how can we enforce cmdkey to add credential for all VM users as of now when the powershell script run through VM custom extension the user is NT AUTHORITY / SYSTEM how can we change the user which is deploying the script.

Comment: Did anyone find a workaround for this issue yet?